# How to Join or search Id with one column which have some Id

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables:

```
Student         Conference
+----+------+   +----+-------+---------------+
| id | name |   | id | name  | ref_studentId |
+----+------+   +----+-------+---------------+
|  1 | jack |   |  1 | Rose  | 1,12          |
|  2 | kai  |   |  2 | White | 12            |
|  3 | wind |   |  3 | Black | 1,12,12356    |
+----+------+   +----+-------+---------------+
```

And I want to join them together with `studentid` or search for `studentid` in `conference` table.

Comment: Don't store serialized datas. Think about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Please try to avoid images where text would be sufficient. Adding text-tables would make the question easier to read. The question would also need details, do you have two lists to join? or a database query? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the LINQ [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins) method to achieve what you want:

```cs
var result = dataContext.Students.Join(dataContext.Conferences,
                                     st => st.id, 
                                     cf => cf.ref_studentId, 
                                     (student, conference) => new { ... });
```

Although I would strongly recommend using the Entity Framework [Navigation Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/bb738520(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), using which the above can be done more easily:

```
var result = dataContext.Student.Include(st => st.conference);
```

**Update:**

Please note that the above LINQ Query will fail to execute unless you will fix your `Conference` Table design, which is against [SQL Normalization Forms](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) (specifically the 1st Normal Form), saying that:

> Each sell should be single-valued.

That means that you shouldn't have a comma (or any other character) separated values in your table columns.

To make the above query work, you have to make the `ref_studentId` contain only a single value for the `StudentId`:

```
Conference
+----+--------+-----------+
| ID |  Name  | StudentId |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | Rose   |         1 |
|  2 | Rose   |        12 |
|  3 | White  |        12 |
|  4 | Black  |         1 |
|  5 | Black  |        12 |
|  6 | Black  |     12356 |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

But to be honest, this one too will not match the SQL Normalization rules.
Specifically, the [2nd Normal Form](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/), saying that:

> All Attributes (non-key columns) should be dependent on a Key.

And the [4th Normal form](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/), saying that:

> There should be no multi-value dependencies (`Rose ⟶ 1`, `Rose ⟶ 12`)

The correct solution would be to create another table for the Student⟶Conference relations.

```
Conference        ConferencesStudents
+----+-------+    +----+--------------+-----------+ 
| ID | Name  |    | ID | ConferenceID | StudentId |
+----+-------+    +----+--------------+-----------+
|  1 | Rose  |    |  1 |            1 |         1 |
|  2 | White |    |  2 |            1 |        12 |
|  3 | Black |    |  3 |            2 |        12 |
+----+-------+    |  4 |            3 |         1 |
                  |  5 |            3 |        12 |
                  |  6 |            3 |     12356 |
                  +----+--------------+-----------+
```

Now, for this one the LINQ query will be:

```cs
dataContext.ConferencesStudents.Join(dataContext.Students,
        cf => cf.ConferenceID,
        st => st.ID,
        (conferencesStudents, student) => new { conferencesStudents, student })
    .Join(dataContext.Conferences,
        cfSt => cfSt.conferencesStudents.ConferenceID,
        cf => cf.ID, 
        (cfSt, conference) =>
        new
        {
            Student = cfSt.student,
            Conference = conference
        });
```

*Note: for the above, I've used the Anonymous Types just for demonstration and my strong advice would be to use real class Models instead.*

OR

By using the same [Navigation Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/bb738520(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) (in case if you correctly had defined the EF relations) you can have a simpler version:

```cs
dataContext.ConferenceStudents.Include(cf => cf.Conferences)
                              .Include(cf => cf.Students)
```

---

**Update 2:**

I hate to say it but there is a kind of workaround in case if you can't change the Database design:

```cs
var results = (
    from c in dataContext.Conference.ToList() // populating all Conferences
    from s in dataContext.Students.ToList()   // populating all Students
    where c.ref_studentId.Split(',').Contains(s.id.ToString())
    select new
    {
        Student = s,
        Conference = c
    }).ToList();
```

*Note: this WILL NOT BE EFFECTIVE from the application performance perspective.*

The better alternative compared to the above could be to write [Stored Procedure](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx) and call it from the EF.

Comment: Hi Arsen, code of you same : 
var result = from student in this.context.set<STUDENT>()
                   join conference in this.context.set<CONFERENCE> on student.id equal conference.ref_studentId
=>>>>>> it don't work because ref_studentId equals many student.id and it's string instead of long.

Comment: @MinhKhai, I've updated my answer. Hope that will help )

Comment: Thank you. I know it but I don't change DB because  I don't have permission.

Comment: @MinhKhai, ok, in that case, please check the "Update 2".

Comment: No, I used to do it. Thank you very much. I think will good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a fiddle for you - if there are any questions feel free to ask.

Btw: This solution solves your question. The data-structure itself is ugly and should be normalized.

```
void Main()
{
    var students = new List<Student>
    {
        new Student { Id = 1, Name = "jack" },
        new Student { Id = 12, Name = "kai" },
        new Student { Id = 12356, Name = "wind" }
    };
    
    var conferences = new List<Conference>
    {
        new Conference { Id = 1, Name = "Rose", RefIds = "1,12" },
        new Conference { Id = 2, Name = "White", RefIds = "12" },
        new Conference { Id = 25, Name = "Black", RefIds = "1,12,12356" }
    };
    
    var result = students.Select(s => new Tuple<int, Conference[]>(s.Id, conferences.Where(c => c.RefIds.Split(",").Contains(s.Id.ToString())).ToArray()));
}

// Define other methods, classes and namespaces here
public class Student
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Conference
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string RefIds {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Linq query you know. I used to check it same you but split didn't run. ERROR when time out And i wanto get id of conferences.

Comment: @MinhKhai, split doesn't work, because LINQ to Entities doesn't support custom predicates. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities) is the List of supported methods.